# Асинхронный запрос с интервалом 1000 мс?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как делать простой запрос с интервалом 1000 мс, и каждый раз ПЕРЕЗАПИСАТЬ данные, которые приходят. То есть новые данные затерезить от старого.

```js
function getRequest() {
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
}

setInterval(getRequest, 1000)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, перечитывайте свои вопросы, из-за небрежности их порой трудно понять. Например, "новые данные затерезить от старого" — не могу угадать, на что исправить)

Comment: Разрешите объяснить - приходять данные и отображаются только последные данные, у меня в коде появляются стратые и новые, а нужно только новые (синоним актуальные данные. последные)

Comment: Не совсем ясно, где вы их отображаете. Код отображает данные в консоли. Вам нужно, чтобы старые данные исчезали и вместо них в консоли появлялись новые?

Comment: Да, верно. Всё правильно пока результат будет в консоле

Comment: @babakov.roman678, если речь про консоль браузера - то единственный способ в ней что-то изменить - это очистить - больше нет вариантов.

Comment: [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1180028/2659) писал ответ на точно такой же вопрос

Comment: вопрос разные .... у меня запрос просто делается каждые 1000 мс и мне нужно показывать последные данные вот и всё ....

Answer (score 4):

Добавьте вызов `console.clear()`:

```js
function getRequest() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((json) => { console.clear(); console.log(json); });
}

setInterval(getRequest, 1000);
```

Comment: Вы что прикалуетесь, простите, но это костыль. Задача - переопределять новые данные

Comment: Простите, тогда я вас не понимаю. Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос больше подробностей, возможно, кто-то другой поймёт вас лучше.

Comment: Реализовать асинхронный циклический запрос на сервер с периодичностью 1 секунда API