# Как правильно сделать запрос на сервер для выгрузки сообщения

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Мне нужно вывести сообщения на страницу, которые отправляются с моей страницы и со страницы моих подписчиков.
У меня есть массив на сервере с данными полученный с помощью get запроса

```
0: {_id: "5f65ef3c9d06ce06be9947a8", userId: "5f65a0f19d06ce06be9945d8", message: "weds", datetime: "2020-09-19T11:45:00.441Z", user: {…}}
1: {_id: "5f65ef839d06ce06be9947ab", userId: "5f65a0f19d06ce06be9945d8", message: "jgfh", datetime: "2020-09-19T11:46:11.645Z", user: {…}}
2: {_id: "5f65ef879d06ce06be9947ac", userId: "5f65a24c9d06ce06be9945d9", message: "Hello, world!", datetime: "2020-09-19T11:46:15.285Z", user: {…}}
3: {_id: "5f65ef879d06ce06be9947ad", userId: "5f65a0f19d06ce06be9945d8", message: "fgkh", datetime: "2020-09-19T11:46:15.363Z", user: {…}}
4: {_id: "5f65eff19d06ce06be9947af", userId: "5f65a0f19d06ce06be9945d8", message: "erw", datetime: "2020-09-19T11:48:01.906Z", user: {…}}
5: {_id: "5f65f0039d06ce06be9947b2", userId: "5f65a0f19d06ce06be9945d8", message: "yhe", datetime: "2020-09-19T11:48:19.169Z", user: {…}}
```

С помощью SetInterval() мне нужно вывести новые сообщения, если они есть.

```
setInterval(() => {
    (async () => {
      let response = await $.get(
        'http://146.185.154.90:8000/blog/botagoz.aimkulova@gmail.com/posts'
      );
      console.log(response)
      let lastDate = response[response.length - 1]['datetime'];
      let newResponse = await $.get(
        `http://146.185.154.90:8000/blog/botagoz.aimkulova@gmail.com/posts?datetime=${lastDate}`
      );
      for (let k in newResponse) {
        showPost(newResponse[k]['user']['firstName'] + ' ' + newResponse[k]['user']['lastName'], newResponse[k]['message']);
      };
    })();
  }, 3000);
```

Пробовал два варианта указать  `let lastDate = response[response.length - 1]['datetime'];`
но тогда сообщения выводяться после перезагрузки страницы, а если

```
 let lastDate = response[response.length - 2]['datetime'];
```

то сообщения добавляются по мере поступления, но последнее сообщение добавляется безконечно, пока его место не займет следующее.
Подскажите как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const postsStore = new Set();

let f;
(f = async () => {
  console.log('run...');
  try {
    await handlePosts();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  setTimeout(f, 3000);
})();

async function handlePosts() {
  const posts = await apiPosts();
  for (const post of posts) {
    if (!postsStore.has(post._id)) {
      postsStore.add(post._id);
      showPost(post);
    }
  }
}

async function apiPosts() {
  const res = await fetch('http://146.185.154.90:8000/blog/botagoz.aimkulova@gmail.com/posts');
  return res.json();
}

function showPost(post) {
  console.log(
    post.user.firstName,
    post.user.lastName,
    post.message
  );
}
```